# Another one problem with legends on GraphicsGrid

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I have used ListLinePlot to generate this grid of plots:

[image]

and I want to add a legend in Row Layout below this grid. My code, has as follows:

```
graphs = Table[
   ListLinePlot[
    Table[Transpose@{vdd, power[[i, j, All]]}, {j, 1, Wl}],
    PlotLabel -> "T=" <> ToString[T[[i]]] <> "\[Degree]C",
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
    FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(V\), \(DD\)]\)(V)","P(nW)"},
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
    ImageSize -> Medium
    ],
   {i, 1, Tl}];
a = {graphs[[1 ;; 3]], graphs[[4 ;; 6]]};
grid = GraphicsGrid[a, Spacings -> Scaled[0], 
   AspectRatio -> 0.6/GoldenRatio];
```

where vdd[[...]], W[[...]], T[[...]],power[[...,...,...]] are lists with the measured values and each colored curve in the above plots, corresponds for a different (but known) value of W.

I was thinking to use

```
Column[{grid, 
  LineLegend[{...colors...}, Table[ToString[W[[n]]]<>"nm",{n,1,Wl}], 
   LegendLayout -> "Row"]}]
```

but I cannot generate the default colour pallete, which Mathematica uses. Also, I need the legend to be justified to the center (presentation purposes, as you can see).

Any help please?

Comment: Default colors: `ColorData[1, "ColorList"]`.

Comment: Thank you kguler. `Column[{grid, LineLegend[ColorData[1, "ColorList"], Table[ToString[Round@W[[n]]] <> "nm", {n, 1, Wl}], LegendLayout -> "Row"]}]` . The problem now is that the legend entries are not in one row and they are not justified. Anyway great help in so little time!

Comment: `LineLegend[1, labels,...]` is the shorter version of `LineLegend[ColorData[1,"ColorList"], labels, ...]`. To prevent line-wrapping you can use something like `LineLegend[1, labels, 
 LegendLayout -> (Pane[Row[Flatten@#, Spacer[3]], 1200] &)]` or `LineLegend[1, labels, 
 LegendLayout -> (Pane[Grid[{Flatten@#}], 1200] &)]`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this could be solved by

```
defcol[n_] := ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[n]];
Legended[Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x]^2, Cos[x]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}],
 Placed[LineLegend[
   {defcol[1], defcol[2], defcol[3]},
   {"S", "S2", "C"},
   LegendLayout -> "Row"], {0.5, -0.1}]]
```

[image]

The position of Legend is defined by option `{0.5, -0.1}`

This could be applied for any combination of graphical objects, so in your case put `Legended` around your `GraphicsGrid`